# Variation on stones in buckets

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

This is a spinoff, see [Collecting stones in n buckets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/242388/41291). Frankly speaking my only motivation is that I became curious: what happens if one redistributes the stones into the same buckets?

More rigorously - there are $n$ stones distributed in $n$ buckets (initially one stone in each bucket). At each step the content of some randomly chosen bucket is removed from it and added to the content of another randomly chosen bucket.

It seems that, just like in that original question, eventually all stones gather in one of the buckets. However my experiments show that this happens way more slowly than in the situation of the original question (there, steps consisted of $n$ of our steps, and the stones were put into new collection of empty buckets; please have a look for precise formulation, informative answer by Douglas Zare and interesting comments by Aaron Meyerowitz).

So the questions are - is it indeed true that the stones come all together with probability 1 and that this happens more slowly than in that case originally described by Maurizio Monge?

Comment: This is an irreducible finite-state Markov chain, so the probability is 1 that we will reach any state. Perhaps the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this chain are already known.

Comment: @RichardStanley We remove **all** stones from a bucket and add them all to another one. I mean, the number of empty buckets never decreases. I cannot say anything rigorously but I think this means the only stable final states are those with a single nonempty bucket.

Comment: Oops, I misread the problem. In your Markov chain, all the states that don't have $n$ stones in one bucket are transient, and the others are recurrent. The probability is 1 that we will eventually reach a recurrent state.

Comment: @RichardStanley I see, thanks. In comments and answers to that original question (with slightly different conditions), the number of steps to reach a recurrent state with probability 1 was estimated to be close to $n\log n$. Do you think something similar holds here?

Comment: Whenever there are $i$ buckets left, the probability that the number of non-empty buckets decreases at the next step is $i(i-1)/n(n-1)$. So, the waiting time to decrease the number of buckets by $1$ is exponential with mean $n(n-1)/i(i-1)$. Summing this up, we see that the expected time to having just one bucket is approximately $n^2$.

Comment: @BorisBukh Great! Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @BorisBukh In fact my experiments seem to contradict this - for 100 trials with $n=1000$ average number of steps to reach all-stones-in-one-bucket state is around 7000

Comment: @BorisBukh Oops sorry I just realized that I skipped cases when empty bucket is chosen. Btw if one also skips cases when the content is moved **into** empty bucket (which does not change the distribution) then the average number of steps seems to be $n$.

Comment: I do not make this into an answer because this question is off-topic for the website, since it is not at research level. It should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @BorisBukh Well it is a variation on another question which was quite well received, and I think rightly so